# How to know which projects use a maven dependency in JFrog Artifactory?

Tags: maven, artifactory

In my organization there are multiple projects (usually services) that are not necessarily uploaded to our maven Artifactory, while there are projects (usually organization libraries) that are uploaded to Artifactory.
The service project may depend on the library project and pull their artifacts from our maven repository.

I'm interested to know if there is a way to list which projects in my organization pull a given dependency on Artifactory, in other words - which projects use a certain library in my organization.

Comment: If those artifacts are not uploaded to Artifactory, there is little that can be done.

Comment: @JFabianMeier. Meaning that Artifactory does show usages between managed artifacts?